# Function works more times, than needs

Tags: javascript

I have dynamically created elements. In vanilla JS we can communicate with such elements only with `document.addEventListener('click',function(){//do smth});`. So I have a script, which takes dynamically created buttons and adds event listener for them.

Problem is when I press some button one time, it's ok, but then script starts to count clicks and do code in `btn.addEventListener('click', function(){ //do smth });` according to count of clicks. For example, I click 1 time - script makes 1 time, I click 2 times - script makes 3 times, I click 3 times - script makes 6 times, cause he counted all clicks. How can I resolve this problem?

```js
document.addEventListener('click', addInCart);

function addInCart(){
    
    const productBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.product__btn');
    for(let btn of productBtns){
        btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
            //do smth
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you binding document's click event? can't you just register the button click events one time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because each time you click on the document will recall the function again, add {once: true} to avoid that.

```
document.addEventListener('click', addInCart, {once: true});

function addInCart(){

    const productBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.product__btn');
    for(let btn of productBtns){
        btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
            //do smth
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use **.onclick = function() { ... }** instead of **.addEventListener('click', function() { ... })**

```
document.addEventListener('click', addInCart);

function addInCart(){

    const productBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.product__btn');
    for(let btn of productBtns){
        btn.onclick = function(){
            //do smth
        };
    }
}
```